# Сравнение двух массивов и вывод уникальных значений

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива, например:

`mas1 = ["some1","some2","some3", "some4"];`

`mas2 = ["some1","some5","some3"];`

Нужно сравнить эти 2 массива и вывести уникальное значение, в данном случае -  `"some5"`

Как смержить масивы и вывести результат без дубликатов я знаю, а вот как сравнить 2 массива и вывести уникально значение - нет.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте классическое решение. Заводите хеш (в javascript - это обычный ассоциативный массив), ключами которого будут элементы массива, а значениями - кол-во повторений. Дальше пробегаетесь по каждому массиву и если в хеше нет - добавляем ключ и значение 1. Если ключ уже есть - увеличиваем значение на 1.

Теперь, ищем в хеше те ключи, где значение равно единице. Это и будут уникальные значения. Этот способ быстрый и вряд ли существует быстрее (в любом случае нужно просмотреть все элементы массива).

Этот способ можно улучшить. Для элементов первого массива увеличиваем на 1, а для второго на 2. Тогда в хеше для уникальных значений будет либо 1 либо 2 (сразу знаем где) и 3 для общих элементов. Но если в массивах будут повторяющиеся элементы, тогда может быть бяка. Но решается очень просто - нужно брать не 1 и 2, а 1 и 1000000. И если повторов будет меньше миллиона - все ок.

Способ, описанный @TheDoctor прост, но при больших массивах будет сильнее тупить (потому что у него сложность квадратичная).

Есть ещё один способ, который заключается в том, что массивы нужно предварительно отсортировать, а потом организовать "паралельный проход" по двум массивам. Кодируется немножко сложно, но интересно.

Comment: В задании не было сказано что массивы огромные. А вот способ выше....

Comment: вот вот. А потом браузер кушает несколько гигов памяти, виним прозводителя браузера... А виноват программист, который "эх, работает - пусть работает, пользователь доставит полоску памяти и процессор"

Comment: Будь проще. Представленные массивы невелики. Да и на 1.000.000 я не видел, он сам по себе извращение.

Comment: я не написал, что мой способ лучше и должен применятся всегда. Я описал когда мой код будет лучше.

Comment: Тогда ОК, ты крут :)

Comment: @KoVadim Последняя фраза вашего ответа хоть как-то претендует на интересный вопрос :) Только в таком решении любопытнее найти все уникальные, а не только в одном массиве относительно второго Но, к сожалению, автору вопроса это не надо :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the Google, Luke!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026828/4733017

```js
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i){return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

var mas1 = ["some1","some2","some3", "some4"],
    mas2 = ["some1","some5","some3"];

var result = mas2.diff(mas1);
console.info(result); // ["some5"]
```

Comment: Справедливости ради, "SO на русском" был запущен как раз для тех, кто по каким-то причинам не пользуется оригинальным SO.

Comment: Справедливости ради, ответ - они и в SO ответ. SO.RU для русскоязычных программистов, а не русских просителей.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же использовать Lodash. Он отлично подходит для работы с коллекциями, например difference:
https://lodash.com/docs#difference

```
_.difference([1, 2, 3], [4, 2]);
// → [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант:

```js
let mas1 = ["some1","some2","some3", "some4"];

let mas2 = ["some1","some5","some3"];

mas2.filter((a)=> mas1.indexOf(a)== -1)
```