# Найти совпадающие значения в массивах Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

Всем добра! Есть два массива разной длины:

```js
var a= ['Весна','Зима','Лето','Осень']
var b=['Добро','Зима','Собака']
```

Как сравнить массивы и вывести в третий массив совпадающие значения (в данном случае `Зима`) ?

`

Comment: Это можно сделать последовательным перебором массивов, если массивы не отсортированы. Если же массивы отсортированы, то один массив придется последовательно перебирать, а во втором массиве устраивать двоичный поиск.

Comment: И исправьте заголовок: "Найти одинаковые значения в массивАХ" Или лучше использовать слово "совпадающие"

Comment: [хороший ответ на эту тему по соседству](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428812/221740)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var a = ['Весна','Зима','Лето','Осень'],
    b = ['Добро','Зима','Собака'];

var array3 = a.filter(function(obj) { return b.indexOf(obj) >= 0; });
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Обыскал весь гугл ничего не нашел...

Comment: @Alex, как быть если таких массивов n